# Implementing Floating Action Button on a Fragment Class

Tags: android, android-fragments, floating-action-button, appcompatactivity

Hi I want to add Floating Action Button on a Fragment Class, but when ever I add implements AppCompatActivity I get this error:

"getLoaderManager()' in 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' 
clashes with 'getLoaderManager()' in 'android.app.Activity'; attempting to use incompatible return type"

public class home extends Fragment implements AppCompatActivity{

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    return rootView;

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: remove `implements AppCompatActivity`  it is a fragment you are not extending activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove "implements AppCompatActivity" from the fragment and add "extends AppCompatActivity" into the activity which holds the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but for anyone else looking for this solution,
Just **write return view in the last** just before the closing bracket of onCreateView.

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer, or just post it as a comment to the question).

Answer (score 0):

you return the rootview before actually using the fab.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
```